# Ionic App does not launch in test flight when using cordova-geofence-plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

We are using cordova-geofence-plugin in our Ionic app and it works fine when we build and run the app from Xcode. But when we deploy the app on test flight for testing, the app does not launch at all or the app crashes. We narrowed the issue down to the Geofence plugin because once we remove the plugin from the app and upload to testflight, the app works fine.
Let me know how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to compile the build using swift 2.3 syntax and then it worked as expected on TestFlight.